# Activating NSLayoutConstraint in `cellForRowAt` is not rendering until after scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, nslayoutconstraint

I need to support `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` (for dynamic height) with variations in the constraints: some need to be active, some not.

I setup the storyboard with `aConstraint` **not** installed, and `bConstraint` installed. I activate/deactivate them on need in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! {
        didSet {
            tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 10
            tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }
    }
}

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var aConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var bConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        cell.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([cell.aConstraint])
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([cell.bConstraint])
        } else {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([cell.bConstraint])
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([cell.aConstraint])
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

#### Issue

The initial visible layout is ignoring all those activations/deactivations, and all the cells are identical to the original storyboard state.

You will notice that the correct constraints are only applied after scrolling.

#### Attempts

I did try without success some `cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints(); cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded(); cell.layoutIfNeeded(); ...`

Sample project shared on https://github.com/Coeur/dynamic-cell-height

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup storyboard with both 'aConstraint' and 'bConstraint' installed, but put a lower priority on 'aConstraint' to remove warnings and it works :)

Comment: It works with both `aConstraint` and `bConstraint` set on priority 999. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems setting up constraints in your code.

#### 1.

UILabel intrinsicContentSize will participate auto layout.
Auto layout system will create a width and height constraints based on intrinsicContentSize.

You explicitly set a height constraint of the label in xib file, causing an ambiguity, then added a vertical centre Y constraint to cover the problem.

#### 2

If you want to try active or deactivate constraints, you may want to do that with a simple UIView.

#### 3

If you want to do various height rows, take advantage of intrinsicContentSize, and set preferredWidth of UILabel.

Comment: UILabel removed on github. The focus of the question is that activating a non-installed constraint in `cellForRowAt` has no effect until scrolling is done.